# Select minimal rows until sum of a column greater than a value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (orders) in Postgresql, schema and data is like this:

```
+----+---------+------+-------+------+--------+
| id | symbol  | qty  | price | side | status |
+----+---------+------+-------+------+--------+
| 1  | BTCUSDT | 0.02 | 6500  | SELL | NEW    | 
+----+---------+------+-------+------+--------+
| 2  | BTCUSDT | 1.00 | 6550  | SELL | NEW    |
+----+---------+------+-------+------+--------+
| 3  | BTCUSDT | 0.03 | 6600  | SELL | NEW    |
+----+---------+------+-------+------+--------+
```

I want select rows where side is SELL and status is NEW, order by price ascending until sum(qty) is greater than 0.5, so the result should select id 1 and 2 for me

when I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT *, SUM(qty) OVER (ORDER BY price ASC) as total_qty FROM orders 
       WHERE symbol = 'BTCUSDT' AND side = 'SELL' AND status = 'NEW'
    ) AS o WHERE o.total_qty <= 0.5
```

it just return the first row (id: 1), I need a query return 1 and 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want all the rows until the row where the sum is equal or exceeds `0.5`.
This means that if you subtract `qty` from the sum of the last row that you want returned the result must be less than `qty`.
Subtract `qty` from the sum and remove the equal sign from the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT o.id, o.symbol, o.qty, o.price, o.side, o.status 
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(qty) OVER (ORDER BY price ASC) - qty as total_qty 
  FROM orders 
  WHERE symbol = 'BTCUSDT' AND side = 'SELL' AND status = 'NEW'
) AS o 
WHERE o.total_qty < 0.5
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xM7jv5epRmzRN72xhepon/2).
Results:

```
| id  | symbol  | qty  | price | side | status |
| --- | ------- | ---- | ----- | ---- | ------ |
| 1   | BTCUSDT | 0.02 | 6500  | SELL | NEW    |
| 2   | BTCUSDT | 1.00 | 6550  | SELL | NEW    |
```

Comment: Please Explain the solution

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that we get all records. I often get `n - 1` records for the provided value where the sum of all records quantities is still less than the provided quantity. Sometimes it works as expected, but it does not seem to be guaranteed.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell can you reproduce this with samle data in the fiddle link in my answer?

Comment: Additionally the total quantity doesn't seem to work correctly...? It repeats when it shouldn't? You can see that here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xM7jv5epRmzRN72xhepon/12

Comment: You can see incorrect results here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xM7jv5epRmzRN72xhepon/13

Comment: @DouglasGaskell (1) In your first sample data the query returns the first 3 rows of the table (as it should) without any repetitions. You can see ids 1, 2 and 3. (2) in your 2nd sample data you have duplicate prices which is not what the OP contains. In this case the order of the rows is not uniquly defined. For this case the ORDER BY clause of the window function must be adjusted to: `OVER (ORDER BY price, id)`

Comment: @DouglasGaskell https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xM7jv5epRmzRN72xhepon/14

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep two `SUM`s. One for the current row and another for the previous row. Then, filtering is easy. For example:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT *, 
    SUM(qty) OVER (partition by side, status ORDER BY price ASC) as total_qty,
    SUM(qty) OVER (partition by side, status ORDER BY price ASC
      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_total_qty
  FROM orders 
  WHERE symbol = 'BTCUSDT' AND side = 'SELL' AND status = 'NEW'
) AS o 
WHERE coalesce(prev_total_qty, 0) <= 0.5
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pdPTRGH6pZaofY2qFWuhdw/0).

Answer (score 0):

You are very much on the right track.  The issue is that the cumulative sum *includes* the current row.  So, your `where` clause filters it out when it passes 0.5.  The simple solution is to subtract out the value from the current row:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT o.*, SUM(qty) OVER (ORDER BY price ASC) as total_qty
      FROM orders o
      WHERE symbol = 'BTCUSDT' AND side = 'SELL' AND status = 'NEW'
     ) o
WHERE o.total_qty - o.qty <= 0.5;
```

You can also use a window frame as Impaler does, but that introduces the problem of `NULL` values on the first row.  You can also subtract out the amount in the subquery as forpas does.  In all cases, the idea is the same:  you need the accumulated quantity *before* each row.

Comment: This query fails in the case where qty = 0.5 in the 1st row, because in this case the result should be only the 1st row but it returns 2: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xM7jv5epRmzRN72xhepon/4

Comment: @forpas . . . The question reads:  "order by price ascending until sum(qty) is greater than 0.5,".

Comment: But the OP's condition: `WHERE o.total_qty <= 0.5` implies until sum is equal or exceeds  0.5. For the sample data posted the expected result contains 1 extra row because the sum is not equal to 0.5.

Comment: This does not seem to guarantee all rows to fulfill the value. I am often receiving a sum of quantities that are *just* under the provided amount. In these cases the `o.total_qty - o.qty` actually makes no difference in the result.